# weblogic logback configuration for each web application

Tags: logging, weblogic

We have almost 10 different web application which is deployed in weblogic 12c. Each app uses one or two common java lib(custom domain common code). We would like to generate one log file for each web app. Does anyone know what is the best way to achieve this?

Or if someone has better idea, we are open for this.

All we need is log file for each app and should be rolling based on size and archive it without affecting performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as each application has a local logback.xml file, you will get separate log file for each application. Be sure to drop each application log into its own folder. We use something like this:

```
<rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
<fileNamePattern>ApplicationName/logFile.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
<maxHistory>10</maxHistory>
</rollingPolicy>
```

Comment: Thanks Brian for the help. Is it possible all of them share the same logback? If not then is there any way we have centralized mechanism to control log level.

Comment: We set a JVM system property in the WebLogic start script. You can then use this value to set the log level across all applications. For instance, set a system property called loglevel and then in the logback config file use ${loglevel}.